# Daily temperature simulation/forecast with Arima/HW

Tags: r, rstudio, forecasting, weather

I have a time series of daily temperature from 1960 to 2015, and would like to forecast for 2016. My goal is to use a simple method while still be able to capture the trend and seasonality of the data over time. (I actually only care about the weather condition from May to August, but not sure if I can just use data from May to August in the past years to get a convincing forecast, so I am forecasting for a year)

I tried auto.arima, it suggested an order of (2,0,1), but the results seemed pretty bad (see plot)[forecasts from arima][1]

In addition, I tried HoltWinters smoothing method and got a seemingly reasonable result. However I don't know if this method is good at forecasting temperature.
[forecast from HW][2]

Comment: Your question is much too broad. Please focus it. Perhaps read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I too am hesitant to provide an answer without more information; however, I will suggest that for someone without a lot of experience in time series forecasting, the auto.arima function in the "forecast" package is excellent.  It has a built in optimization that searches for the best ARIMA order (p,d,q).  Here is some example code:

```
install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)

set.seed(1234)
tsdatav <- (seq(1:300) + rnorm(300, 1000, 10))
myts <- ts(tsdatav, frequency = 365, start = c(2017, 6))
mytsfit <- auto.arima(myts)
mytsfit  #to my example data, fit an ARIMA(5,1,0) with drift
mytsforecast <- forecast(mytsfit, 50, level = c(80, 95))
plot(mytsforecast)
```

Notice that in the forecast function, you can set how many periods you want to forecast out as well as confidence intervals (in addition to the point forecast).

Duke has an excellent website on ARIMA forecasting at https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim.htm

Again, this is just one suggestion.  There are many forecasting approaches that work better than others given problem specifics.

Comment: Even though the question was probably too broad, this is a good answer. +1

Comment: I used auto.arima function to predict the next 365 days temperature, however, it seems that the prediction did not capture the seasonality. I also used HoltWinters smoothing method and the result seems ok by plotting. But it is not really convincing. I will edit my question above.